# AND/OR trees queries in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm representing AND/OR trees in Neo4j as in the figure below (with AND and OR nodes and corresponding relationships). The tree's leaves are properties representing boolean values (green = true, red = false).

Now, I'm looking for an algorithm (or cypher query) to traverse each tree to know whether there is at least a valid path (a set of leaves that satisfies the AND/OR conditions) from the leaves or not to the tree's root. For example, in the figure there is such a path, thus the algorithm should return true (and perhaps also the nodes part of the path).
[AND/OR tree in Neo4J](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52UuZ.png)

example data:

```
MERGE (a:ROOT_NODE{key:'a'})
MERGE (b:AND_NODE{key:'b'})
MERGE (c:OR_NODE{key:'c'})
MERGE (d:OR_NODE{key:'d'})
MERGE (e:AND_NODE{key:'e'})
MERGE (f:RED{key:'f'})
MERGE (g:GREEN{key:'g'})
MERGE (h:RED{key:'h'})
MERGE (i:RED{key:'i'})
MERGE (j:GREEN{key:'j'})
MERGE (k:GREEN{key:'k'})

MERGE (k)-[:AND]->(e)
MERGE (j)-[:AND]->(e)
MERGE (e)-[:OR]->(d)
MERGE (i)-[:OR]->(d)
MERGE (f)-[:OR]->(c)
MERGE (g)-[:OR]->(c)
MERGE (h)-[:OR]->(c)
MERGE (c)-[:AND]->(b)
MERGE (d)-[:AND]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:OR]->(a)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "valid path"? Can you elaborate or provide an example?

Comment: I slightly changed the post description. By a valid path, I mean a set of leaves that satisfies the AND/OR parent conditions, up to the root. Looking at the example, from the bottom-left, the AND node is satisfied because the two leaves are green, consequently also the next OR node, as well as the OR node on the right (because there is at least one leaf green), thus we can get to the root.

Comment: you may want to check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71815007/given-a-neo4j-tree-with-a-wehigt-on-its-leaves-how-do-i-return-for-each-node-th/71820674#71820674).