# Given a neo4j tree with a weight on its leaves, how do I return for each node the weight of all of its offspring?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653609/and-or-trees-queries-in-neo4j), I tried to understand how do I return for each node the weight of all of its offspring.

One solution I had in mind, is traversing over a tree from the bottom up and return for each node the weight of all of its offspring

For sample data:

```
MERGE (r:RootNode{key:0})
MERGE (a:Node{key:1})
MERGE (b:Node{key:2})
MERGE (c:Node{key:3})
MERGE (d:Node{key:4})
MERGE (e:Leaf{key:5, w:12})
MERGE (f:Leaf{key:6, w:19})
MERGE (g:Leaf{key:7, w:20})
MERGE (h:Leaf{key:8, w:5})
MERGE (i:Leaf{key:9, w:8})

MERGE (a)-[:LINKS]->(r)
MERGE (b)-[:LINKS]->(a)
MERGE (c)-[:LINKS]->(a)
MERGE (d)-[:LINKS]->(a)
MERGE (e)-[:LINKS]->(b)
MERGE (f)-[:LINKS]->(b)
MERGE (g)-[:LINKS]->(c)
MERGE (h)-[:LINKS]->(d)
MERGE (i)-[:LINKS]->(d)
```

I tried to get a list of nodes ordered for calculation, so each father will be calculated after all of its Children are calculated:

```
MATCH (r:RootNode)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(r,{relashishipFilter:"<"})
YIELD nodes
WITH reverse(nodes) as upStream
...
RETURN upStream
```

but I could not find a way to iterate over the list one by one and use its calculation result for next iteration...
I would like to get results like:

```
╒════════════════╕
│"n"             │
╞════════════════╡
│{"key":0,"w":64}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":1,"w":64}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":2,"w":31}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":3,"w":20}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":4,"w":13}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":5,"w":12}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":6,"w":19}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":7,"w":20}│
├────────────────┤
│{"key":8,"w":5} │
├────────────────┤
│{"key":9,"w":8} │
└────────────────┘
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The weight on each node, which is the sum of the weight of its offspring.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's not possible in Cypher. In your question, you specify how the values should be calculated, a sort-of "reverse iteration" that makes me think of recursion. So far all my searches for examples of recursion in Cypher have suggested it's just not possible.

Maybe the solution is to write a custom plugin or use the Neo4j API so you can write more imperative code.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work... unless you execute the query four times. >.< The output is perfect on the fourth run though. :'-)

(Posting as an answer for the formatting.)

```
MATCH (r:RootNode)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(r,{relashishipFilter:"<"})
YIELD nodes
WITH reverse(nodes) as upstream
UNWIND upstream as weightedNode
OPTIONAL MATCH (weightedNode)<-[incomingLink:LINKS]-()
WITH sum(incomingLink.w) + sum(weightedNode.w) AS totalWeight, weightedNode
OPTIONAL MATCH ()<-[outgoingLink:LINKS]-(weightedNode)
SET outgoingLink.w = totalWeight 
RETURN weightedNode.key, totalWeight
ORDER BY weightedNode.key
```

The problem is that the relationship property values don't get updated until the whole query is complete.

Comment: Thank you for taking the challenge:) I'm not sure if I should mark the answer as works...Up voted for now

Comment: Thanks - and agreed, it's not the correct answer. I had a couple of ideas to fix it 1) instead of using relationship properties to store total weights, can you use a map? 2) is there some way to update the graph immediately with the new properties? Although... I'm starting to think the correct answer is, it's not possible to calculate the answer this way using just Cypher.

Comment: Regarding your suggestions of using a map and update, everything is allowed so long it is being done in a query. This is a theoretical question. I assumed such a tree calculation should be possible in neo4j without using external code

Comment: I think the difficulty in this instance comes from specifying _how_ the problem should be solved. "find a way to iterate over the list one by one and use its calculation result for next iteration". Cypher is a declarative language so you would normally tell it _what_ to solve, rather tell it how to solve the problem.

Comment: If you solve the problem with a different solution I will edit the question. Maybe my phrasing was misleading. I'm more interested in the what than the how, although the how is also interesting...The title has the essence

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind how the answer is reached, IE we don't specify this "iterate over the list one by one and use its calculation result for next iteration", then this works:

```
MATCH (n:Node)<-[:LINKS*0..]-(m:Node)
RETURN sum(m.w) AS totalWeight, n.key
```

Comment: OK. You are right. These are two questions and I'm interested in both. I will have to edit and split it.